# Override WooCommerce public function in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

In WooComerce file **class-wc-form-handler.php**
I wanted to override in my child theme just one line where the variable `$redirect`.

What is the best practice in this case ?

**class-wc-form-handler**

```
public function process_registration() {
   if ( ! empty( $_POST['register'] ) ) {
    ...
    // Redirect
    if ( wp_get_referer() ) {
        $redirect = esc_url( wp_get_referer() );
    } else {

          //$redirect = esc_url( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) );
        $redirect = home_url() . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }

    wp_redirect( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', $redirect ) );
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to override any method. As you can see on line where `wp_redirect` there is filter hook. Read more about [`apply_filters`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters).

You can add your own custom filter to the tag `woocommerce_registration_redirect` using [`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter).

Heres how you can do it:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'my_custom_redirect' );

function my_custom_redirect()
{
    return esc_url( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) );
}
```

Place the above code in your child theme `functions.php` file.